# How to change or assign key functionality in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have  bought a keyboard that has Fn key at the left bottom corner. But I'm used to with having Ctrl button there. I can't change it now. Thus, I'm  having trouble with using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. Is there  any way so that I can change/assign Fn+C  and Fn+V for same copy paste functionalities without any other software / apps.

And is there any way I can do that for this  particular keyboard. I don't want to mess up other keyboards.

Comment: what brand of computer are you using? e.g Hp, Dell, Apple...

Comment: @Antz Dell Laptop Inspiron N5110. But  the keyboard is external. Not the one  that comes with the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this by using [Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center)

Using the keyboard that you want to configure, start Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.

From the displayed list of key names, select the key you want to reassign.

In the command list of the key that you want to reassign, select a command.

Or check [remapping your keyboard](https://www.technorms.com/31627/how-to-remap-your-keyboard), [remapping Any Key on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) saw some cool things there that you might also want to try.